# Excel find, match and mark wildcards

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find, match, formula

I am trying to do a search based on values that are in column `B` and find string in column `A`, example:

Column `A`

```
abc, cde | abc, 1234 | cde | abc, etc
```

Column `B`

```
abc, cde
```

I am trying to use values that are in column `B` and search and match in column `A` and return value of match/no match in column `C`.

I tried using `MATCH(B1,A:A)` function and return value of match or no match but its all returning no match and its not searching the values on column `A` that have the |

Any formulas I can use?

Comment: What do you mean by "match/no match". Do you want a True-False like answer ? Also, to figure out what you are trying to do, it may be a good idea to give the answer you would have with the example you give: what you would have in column `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is getting a boolean value, *i.e* `TRUE` or `FALSE`, which tells you if the string in cell `B1` is somewhere in the string value of cell `A1`, you can do

```
=NOT(ISERR(SEARCH(B1,A1)))
```

The `SEARCH` function gets the value in cell `A1` and **tries** to find it within the string value contained in cell `B1`. I say "trie" since it may return an error if it finds nothing.

Thus `ISERR(SEARCH(...))` checks for an error and returns `TRUE` if there is one, which in this case would mean that the velue in cell `B1` does not match the one in cell `A1`.

Finally, to turn the output of function `ISERR` into the boolean answer you want, we negate it, by doing `NOT(ISERR(...))`.

---

#### Example 1

> *Checking whether each string value in column `B` is CONTAIN**ED** in cell `A1`'s string value*

```
    A                          B             C
1   abc, cde | abc, 1234       abc, cde      =NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($B1,$A$1)))
2                              zyy | xww     =NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($B2,$A$1)))
.                              ...           ... 
10                             abc, 1234     =NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($B10,$A$1)))
```

Which returns `TRUE` in cell `C1`, `FALSE` in cell `C2` and `TRUE` in cell `C10`.

***post scriptum*** : Taking a pick at bioschaf's comment may help you to generalize the concept.

---

#### Example 2

> *Checking whether the string value of each cell of column `B` is CONTAIN**ED** in the string value in column `A`'s adjacent cell*

Or using your example.

```
    A               B             C
1   abc | cde       abc      =NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($B1,$A1)))
2   cde | bsd       xxx      =NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($B2,$A2)))
3   aaa | abc       bsd      =NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($B3,$A3)))
```

---

#### Example 3

> *Checking whether each column `A`'s value is CONTAIN**ED** somewhere in column `B`'s range `$B$1:$B$11`*, using **array formula**

```
       A         B              C
1      abc       abc | cde      =NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($A1,$B$1:$B$11))))))
.      ...       ...            ... 
1000   aaa                      =NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($A1000,$B$1:$B$11))))))
```

From which you can drop the `NOT(NOT(...))` part so as to see the number of occurence rather than turning it into boolean values.

---

#### Example 4

> *Checking whether each column `B`'s value CONTAIN**S** at least one of the string value in column `D`'s range `$D$2:$D$5`*, using **array formula**

Using data you give in comment. And showing them in the column you also mention in comment, it follows that we have

```
       B                                                       C           D
1      
2      hardware|information services|information technology                hardware
3      hardware                                                            mobile
4      apps|mobile                                                         3d
5                                                                          computer
```

Thus, if we want to check if each value in column `B` **contains** a word written somewhere in range `D2:D5`, what we can do is (say in column E):

```
    E
1
2   =NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$5,$B2))))))
4   =NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$5,$B3))))))
3   =NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$5,$B4))))))
5
```

Where each of the above formula has to be validated as ***MATRIX-FORMULA*** by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Doing so will render :

```
    E
1
2   TRUE       
4   TRUE
3   TRUE
5
```

In `E2` we have `TRUE` since `hardware|information services|information technology` contains the word `hardware`, actually located at `D2`.

In `E3` we have `TRUE` since `hardware` contains (exactly) the word `hardware`, actually located at `D2`.

In `E4` we have `TRUE` since `apps|mobile` contains the word `mobile`, actually located at `D3`

Comment: And to use that on a range instead of comparing two cells, use =SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH(B1,A1:A10)))) and enter it as array-formula (close cell with CTRL+Shift+Enter)

Comment: I am trying to take column from B like example : B1, B2 compare to A1:A10 and mark on the column C1-C10 whetther its true or false, and this formula is not achieving it?

Comment: its like 
Column A : 
1. abc | cde 
2. cde | bsd 
3. aaa | abc
4. abc | 123
5. aaa | 1234

Column B : 
1. abc
2. xxx
3. bsd

basicly, I want column A compare to value in column B and return true/false in column C

Comment: I tried the formula and still not acting as what it should be, the problem is that column A have 1000 row, and I need to check to column B values that is only 11 row, once lets say I insert formula in the A12 vs B12 it will return value that is wrong, as the column B B12 is empty, where A12 should be checked into column B1-11 to match if the values exists, I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: @Tnerual I tried the update 3 formulas and the formula is populating, but if the column is empty its returning "TRUE" while the rest is FALSE, and even if the data column A : row 10 for example have "abc | def | efg" compared to column B1:B10 that one of the cell consists "abc" its still returning FALSE instead of TRUE, did I miss anything? seems like we need to put wildcard into it??

Comment: @Tnerual yes I agree, but its not working due to column A's value are "abc | bsd" when compared to column B with values "abc" its returning FALSE instead of TRUE

Comment: @Tnerual I tried : =NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$21;$B2)))))) and its still returning false for all, even though there is values that are match :(

Comment: @Tnerual yes i copied and the cell was right b2 and d2:d21 but its returning false, i can send you the xls file if you want to test it :)

Comment: @Tnerual sorry I missed that part, okay here column B : row 2 : hardware|information services|information technology, row 3 : hardware row 4 : apps|mobile 

column D : row 2 : hardware, row3: mobile, row 4: 3d, row 5 : computer, thats it :)

Comment: @Tnerual yes I wanted to search B2's value to D2:D21, sorry forgive my bad understanding of english

Comment: @Boby. See example 4. or example 3 depending on what you really want. And take the time to read ;) The answer is *a priori* under your eyes.

Comment: @Tnerual another question please, is there any other way if the word is found copy to another cell next of it? thank you